# A flash MP3 player that will take a URL and can auto play

Tags: flash, mp3, media-player, url

I am looking for a flash MP3 player that can be accessed using a URL and that can play an MP3 file from another URL but also has the ability to autoplay.

Something like http://mail.google.com/mail/html/audio.swf?audioUrl=audio.mp3, but with the ability to autoplay.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.. There is an autoplay parameter for the Google mail MP3 player:

```
autoplay=true
```

:D